# Publish to Azure Powershell command error: Publish-AzureWebsiteProject : Value cannot be null

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have a web application which was built via `VS 2013`. I am trying to publish it using window power shell cmdlet `(Windows PowerShell ISE (x86)` to Azure but I am continuously getting the error. I did search around but there is very limited info regarding the PowerShell publish command issue.

The command:

```
PS C:\publish> Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name "MySiteName" -Package "MyPackage.Zip"
```

The error details look like below:

> Publish-AzureWebsiteProject : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path2 At line:1 char:1 
>   + Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Name "MySiteName" -Package ".\MyPackage.Zip...
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo  : CloseError: (:) [Publish-AzureWebsiteProject], ArgumentNullException   + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.PublishAzureWebsiteProject

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a known issue with this version.  See if this helps: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1911

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your error is due to the package file "**MyPackage.Zip**" does not exist under the directory "*`C:\publish`*" which you execute your Azure PowerShell command in the Windows PowerShell ISE.

I tested the exact command line with and without the actual package file in the directory and able to reproduce the exact same error and publish successfully.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Which article are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I think you are referring this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722468.aspx, in the article, it says you can use either package file path or project file path as parameter, no mater which way you use, the path is a required field. I use the first option (package path) as parameter, But it throw the exception. 

Regards,

Mark J

Comment: Hi @MarkJ, I edited my answer based on your feedback and my further investigation, thanks and hope it helps you this time!

Comment: Hi @juvchan, I do have the .zip file exist under the C:\Publish. I just wonder is it a possible issue relating the Azure server enviornment?

Comment: What is the Azure PowerShell version you're using?

Comment: I am using Azure PowerShell 1.2.2.